# Python requirements for SUDs

Tags: python, windows-7, suds

I'm a noob to SOAP and SUDs.  I need to install SUDs on a windows 7 machine, on which I have Python 3.2.

I haven't heard of anyone installing SUDs in Python 3+.

Should I install Python 2.7?  Or do I need to go earlier?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look under the overview section you can see that **SUDs** was tested on **Python 3.2** under Windows. On this [website](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) you can also find instructions on how to install **SUDs** for Python using `pip`, easy install or from source.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SUDs hasn't been ported to python 3 yet.  2.7 should run it fine.

Update: I guess there's a fork of suds that works on 3.2: [suds-jurko](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.4.1.jurko.4)

Answer (score 0):

to setup sudo in windows :
- Open a command prompt as before.
- cd \Python27\scripts\
-   now your location is : C\Python27\scripts\
- Type    easy_install suds
[image]